# Locally modify the syntax-table via text-properties

Tags: text-properties, syntax-table

I’m trying to make a particular exclamation point behave like a word constituent (from the point of view of the syntax table), using the `syntax-table` text property, but I can’t get it to work.

In an empty buffer I write an exclamation mark and then evaluate the command `(add-text-properties 1 2 '(syntax-table (2)))`. I think this is what I’m supposed to do.
But `describe-char` on the exclamation mark shows

```
            character: ! (displayed as !) (codepoint 33, #o41, #x21)
[…]
               syntax: .    which means: punctuation
[…]
There are text properties here:
  syntax-table         (2)
```

Note that the text property has been applied, but it is still considered a punctuation character. What am I missing? Do I need to call a function to update it somehow? Other text properties (for instance `display`) are applied automatically.

Comment: You need to set `parse-sexp-lookup-properties` to a non-nil value.

Comment: Thanks! But it’s a bit strange, it means that the `syntax-table` text property is useless otherwise? Why isn’t that on by default?

Comment: "Why isn’t that on by default?" - performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Tobias, you generally need

```
(set (make-local-variable 'parse-sexp-lookup-properties) t)
```

in order for those properties to have an effect.  The reason for it is probably historical and linked to performance, and nobody bothered to try and change it since.

Notice that `syntax-table` text properties are usually set via `syntax-propertize-function`, in which case `syntax-propertize` will take it upon itself to set `parse-sexp-lookup-properties` for you, which is why you don't usually see major modes setting this var explicitly.